# [ERROR]: Pressing the Back button on page MainPage.xaml does not close the dialog box

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, marketplace, childwindow

I am having a problem with the Monitored Test cases "Use of Back Button". I always get the error message

```
[ERROR]: Pressing the Back button on page MainPage.xaml does not close the dialog box
```

I'm pretty sure, that I close all `Dialog`s, when the Back-Button is pressed. I even null them out,
after returning a valid `DialogResult`.

Are there eventually any `Controls`(I only use standard `Controls`) that are classified as `Dialog`, like `ContextMenus`
or other `Controls`?

And how can I know, which `Dialog` is meant? Are there any protocol files or something, that tells me in detail,
how the test was passed? Output Windows or something else in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Are you talking about the MessageBox? code might be useful to explain.

Comment: Do you use the 'Popup' control somewhere?

Comment: Hi, no I use a Child Window and open it through a ViewModel. The child window is opened, and I set a property on the ViewModel to indicate, that a Dialog was opened. In MainPage.xaml I override the OnBackKeyPress Method,cancel the event, and Fire an event on the ViewModel, which causes the ChildWindow to close by returning a valid DialogResult. Afterwards I set the CurrentDialog property to null. But the test still says, that I have dialogs open, and that the dialogs don't close when hitting the hardware-back-button.

Comment: Here is the code from OnBackKeyPress: `code` protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
             var currentViewModel = (SkyDriveViewModel)Resources["ViewModel"];
            //close open dialog
             if (currentViewModel.IsDialogOpen)
             {
                 currentViewModel.OnWindowClosed();
                 currentViewModel.IsDialogOpen = false;
                 currentViewModel.CurrentDialog = null;
                 e.Cancel = true;
             }
            base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
        }`code`

Comment: And here the code from within the ChildWindows:`code`void model_CloseWindowEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SkyDriveViewModel model = App.ViewModelForApp as SkyDriveViewModel;
            model.IsDialogOpen = false;
            this.DialogResult = true;
        }

Comment: Initialization of the dialog in the ViewModel `MoveFileDialog dlg = new MoveFileDialog();
                //Set the id of the file to move.
                dlg.FileMoveId = values.FileId;
                dlg.CopyOrMoveCaption = "copy file to";
                dlg.OkButtonCaption = "Copy";
                dlg.CopyOrMoveFiles = "copy";
                dlg.ParentDirectory = values.FileParentId;
                ApplicationBarEnabled = false;
                AppBarCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                IsDialogOpen = true;
                dlg.Show();`

Comment: I posted the question also here, and I have published more code there [http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/97842/583498.aspx#583498]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else coming across this question, there is an answer in the version of this question posted on the MSDN forums:
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/97842/583498.aspx#583498

(There was a ChildWindow which needed to be explicitly closed.)